# How to add onkeydown to body?

Tags: javascript

In my index.html I have this code.
I would need to add `onkeydown` event to that body in Main.onLoad().

Any idea how to do it?

```
<body id="body" 
    onload="Main.onLoad();" 
    onunload="Main.unload();" 
    onmousedown="Main.mouseDown();"
>
```

---

```
<body id="body" 
    onload="Main.onLoad();" 
    onkeydown="TVA.keyDown(event);" 
    onunload="Main.unload();" 
    onmousedown="Main.mouseDown();"
>
```

Comment: Please read about "unobtrusive JavaScript" and avoid eventhandlers in your HTML.

Comment: I understand your point,but I have to solve it in this way for the moment :-( any idea? thanks

Comment: why onkeydown event in body?whats your req?

Comment: What do you mean by _in_ Main.onLoad()

Comment: `onkeydown` should work actually; check that `TVA` object and its `keyDown` handler exists when your body parsed.

Comment: This maybe a browser dependent, but try to attach `onkeydown` to `document` instead of `body` in `onload` handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Javascript block, try to use [`window.onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onkeydown) (*MDN*).

You can also use `document.onkeydown` and `document.body.onkeydown`.

Here is an example for you:

### JavaScript

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)+" --> "+e.keyCode);
};
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLEaF/)

The code above can be put in any valid JavaScript block (such as `Main.onLoad()` function).

Comment: What is exactly the effective difference between `window.onkeydown`, `document.onkeydown`, and `document.body.onkeydown`? I'd say using `window` binds to the viewport, and `document` binds to `<html>`, and `document.body` binds to `<body>`, but is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach listeners like this:
you can pass a function or simply invoke an anonymous one in code.

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown',Main.onLoad);
```

Seems to work on stack overflow when passed to console.

Comment: From the comments: "`... I have to solve it in this way for the moment.`", and beware, where would you place this code?

Comment: Do you need Main.onLoad function to run on keydown?

Answer (score 0):

Usually `onkeydown` can be attached to the elements which can receive focus. In some browsers you can gain focus to the `document.body`, but you can't rely on that. `window` is one of those elements which can gain the focus.

You can try to put the code below to the `head` section of your HTML code, *after* `TVA` is defined.

```
window.onkeydown = TVA.keyDown;
```

Or when using `addEventListener()`:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', TVA.keyDown, false);
```

Comment: rom the comments: "... I have to solve it in this way for the moment.", and beware, where would you place this code?

Comment: @raam86 This is the nearest OP can reliable achieve `with this way`. The place for the snippet is mentioned in my answer: "`... to the head section of your HTML code, after TVA is defined.`"