# Is there a difference between window.onkeydown and document.onkeydown?

Tags: javascript

Most of the code I've seen online uses `document.onkeydown`, but MDN only lists [`window.onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onkeydown). [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17593731) also recommends using `window.onkeydown`. Is there a difference or a reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See the following graphic from [Event dispatch and DOM event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#event-flow):

[image: graphical representation of an event dispatched in a DOM tree using the DOM event flow]

There are three [event phases](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-phase):

> - The **capture phase**: the event object must propagate through the target's ancestors from the [defaultView](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-defaultView) to the target's parent.
>     This phase is also known as the *capturing phase*. Event listeners
>     registered for this phase must handle the event before it reaches its
>     target.
> - The **target phase**: the event object must arrive at the event object's [event target](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-event-target). This phase is also known as the
>     *at-target* phase. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event once it has reached its target. If the [event
>     type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-event-type) indicates that the event must not bubble, the event object
>     must halt after completion of this phase.
> - The **bubble phase**: the event object propagates through the target's ancestors in reverse order, starting with the target's parent
>     and ending with the [defaultView](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-defaultView). This phase is also known as the
>     *bubbling phase*. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event after it has reached its target.

Therefore, the main difference is that event listeners added to `window` will handle the event after event listeners added to `document` in case of bubble phase; and before in case of capture phase.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason to use window over document is because it doesn't have to propagate as far?

Comment: @Yay295 Did you mean the opposite?

Comment: As I understand it, if you use window it goes window->event->window, and if you use document it goes window->document->event->document->window.

Comment: @Yay295 The event flow is always the same, it doesn't depend on your event listeners. But depending on which node you attach your event listener, it will run in a different moment of that event flow.