# I want the white circle(id="spc") to stop when spacebar is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a game, so I want to use spacebar to determine the speed of the ball thrown.But I was unable to do it , I have been trying various websites for answers but I don't understand where the mistake is.

```js
function pausespc(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    spc.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  }
}
```

```css
#speed {
  height: 350px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green);
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 875px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: block;
}

#spc {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  animation: spdc 850ms linear 0s 4 alternate;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes spdc {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 330px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="speed">
  <div id="spc" onkeydown="pausespc(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the variable 'spc' defined anywhere?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): The title should give a short summary of the problem. Introduce the problem before you post any code. (Don't add unnecessary phrases like _"Please help..."_, _"Thank you"_, _"Thanks for reading"_, ...)

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593391/how-to-add-onkeydown-to-body, your event is 32 as Nehal said below

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `if(event.keyCode === 27)`?
The keyCode for space bar is 32.
You can try writing `if(event.keyCode === 32)` and check the results.

Comment: (and by the way, `27` is for `Esc` key)

Comment: this answer is better fit for the comment section, changing it to 32 wont get the desired results since the event should be on the window, body etc. even though you are right about the key